# Overwriting .htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ ?page=search&type=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

This one works great.

When i'm trying to have another .htaccess rule as the following:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/.]+)?$ ?page=profile&name=$1 [L]
```

The first one is overwriting this rule, and when im trying to access **profile/test** I get to the **?page=search** page.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Place your second htaccess rule above first one , so it will working 

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/.]+)?$ ?page=profile&name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ ?page=search&type=$1&city=$2 [L]
```